# Lua Complex Tables/List Sizes

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to find the number of entries for `test[0]`

```
test = {}
test[0] = {}
test[0].x = {}
test[0].x[0] = 1
test[0].x[1] = 1
test[0].x[2] = 1
test[0].y = {}
test[0].y[0] = 1
```

I am expecting `table.getn(test[0])` to be 2 for entries `test[0].x` and `test[0].y` but it results in 0.  Why is this, and what do I need to do to get what I am looking for?

Comment: I found that `for _ in pairs(tab) do count = count + 1 end` works for this issue.

Comment: I wonder what you need this count for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `table.getn` in Lua 5.0 has been replaced by the `#` operator since Lua 5.1

The size of a table is only valid for the sequence part of a table (i.e, with positive numeric keys from `1` to some number `n`, and `n` is the size).

In this example, `test[0]` has only two kesy `"x"` and `"y"`. As a result its size is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

[`table.getn`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#getn) and the lua 5.1 [length operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5) are defined to operate on "lists" or arrays. Your table isn't one. It has no numerical indices.

So the result is undefined in lua 5.1 (though it will be zero here) and 0 in lua 5.0 as the size is defined to be `one less the first integer index with a nil value` which is the integer index `1`.

Also worth noting is that `table.getn(test[0].x)` will return `2` and `table.getn(test[0].y)` will return `0` (since lua arrays start at `1`).